# CallObjectMethod does not return a string

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

My aim is to create an instance of a `Java` class in `C++`, and then call methods defined in the `Java` class.

Here is a summary of my `Java` class :

**EXICodec.java**

```
public class EXICodec {
    ...
    private static String inputXML;
    ...
    public EXICodec()
    {
        System.out.println("Constructor");  
        this.inputXML = "string";
        ...
    }
    ...
    public static void setInputXML(String inXML)
    {
        inputXML = inXML;
    }
    ...
    public static  String getInputXML()
    {
        return inputXML;
    }
```

Here is a summary of the `C++` code used to interact with that class :

**JavaInterface.hh**

```
class JavaInterface
{
    private:
        JNIEnv*     JNIEnvironment;
        JavaVM*     javaVM;
        jclass      javaClass;
        jobject     javaClassInstance;

        jmethodID   IDconstructor;
        jmethodID   IDsetInputXML;
        jmethodID   IDgetInputXML;

    public:
        JavaInterface();                    
        void init_context( void);               
        void init_class( void);
        void init_methods( void);                   

        void setInputXML( std::string);
        std::string getInputXML( void);
}
```

**JavaInterface.cc**

```
void JavaInterface::init_context(){..}    //initiate the JNIEnvironment & javaVM attributes
void JavaInterface::init_class(){..}      //initiate the javaClass attribute
void JavaInterface::init_methods()
{
     this->IDconstructor = this->JNIEnvironment->GetMethodID(this->javaClass, "<init>", "()V");
     if (this->IDconstructor == NULL) 
     {
         throw std::runtime_error("JAVA_INIT_METHOD_EXCEPTION");
     }

     this->IDsetInputXML = this->JNIEnvironment->GetStaticMethodID(this->javaClass, "setInputXML", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
     if (this->IDsetInputXML == NULL) 
     {
         throw std::runtime_error("JAVA_INIT_METHOD_EXCEPTION");
     }

     this->IDgetInputXML = this->JNIEnvironment->GetStaticMethodID(this->javaClass, "getInputXML", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

     if (this->IDgetInputXML == NULL) 
     {
         throw std::runtime_error("JAVA_INIT_METHOD_EXCEPTION");
     }
}      
void JavaInterface::j_constructor()
{
    this->javaClassInstance = this->JNIEnvironment->NewObject(this->javaClass, this->IDconstructor);      
    if (this->javaClassInstance == NULL) 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("JAVA_CONSTRUCTOR_CALL_EXCEPTION");
    }
}

void JavaInterface::j_setInputXML( std::string str)
{   
    jstring argument = this->JNIEnvironment->NewStringUTF(str.c_str());
    this->JNIEnvironment->CallVoidMethod(this->javaClassInstance, this->IDsetInputXML, argument);
}

std::string JavaInterface::j_getInputXML()
{
    jstring javaString = NULL;

    // ---> PROBLEM HERE : javaString is still NULL after the line below : <---
    javaString = (jstring)this->JNIEnvironment->CallObjectMethod(this->javaClassInstance, this->IDgetInputXML, 0);  

    // jString to char*
    const char *nativeString = this->JNIEnvironment->GetStringUTFChars(javaString, JNI_FALSE);
    // char* to std::string
    std::string str(nativeString);

    this->JNIEnvironment->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaString, nativeString);

    return str;
}
```

So my problem is that the call of `CallObjectMethod` does not return anything.
I tried to change the Java method to `static` but it did not change.

More generally, how would you return a string from `Java` to `C++`? Maybe my starting idea is bad.

Comment: Your general approach seems legit to me. Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: I created an MWE, but unfortunately it is not really minimal... it needs some process to initiate the JVM. Anyway...here it is : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0j1093oh8nn7k2x/AAAHUKWS9JifAkXO3z5MSsisa?dl=0

Comment: You need to check for exceptions after calling every JNI method.

Comment: You mean when I create the `jmethodID` objects ? I check it but I removed the code in that example.

Comment: I mean what I said. After every JNI call. What part of 'every' isn't clear to you?

Comment: If the result of the method is `null`, then you will get a `NULL` back, which you probably need to allow for. Otherwise, if you check for exceptions after `CallObjectMethod` and that returns nothing, you should have detected – and probably reported – an exception. Could you tell us **in your question** what happens, and show us the exception, if any? Since these checks are important and can be done in a subroutine, they will not inflate your code too much, so please leave them in the code you post.

Comment: Ok, I am looking for a way to get the exception from JNI and I will edit my code as soon as I can.

Comment: Check out [ExceptionCheck](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#ExceptionCheck) and [ExceptionDescribe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#ExceptionDescribe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, sorry for taking that long, but I got the problem resolved. Basically, it is a little typo causing the havoc (at least in your MWE):

```
 this->IDgetString = this->JNIEnvironment->GetStaticMethodID(this->javaClass
                                    , "getString"
                                    , "(()Ljava/lang/String;");
                                    // ^ This parenthesis must be removed.
```

Furthermore, I noticed you did not initialize the object. I refractored your code to use instace methods instead of static methods and for me, the MWE is running fine.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/gJXWrpzA) is the code for `EXICodec.java` I used and [here](http://pastebin.com/eu2ph1ed) is the code for `JavaInterface.cpp`.

I took a look at you original code again and found something else.

```
void JavaInterface::init_methods()
{
    this->IDconstructor = this->JNIEnvironment->GetMethodID(this->javaClass, "<init>", "()V");
    if (this->IDconstructor == NULL) 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("JAVA_INIT_METHOD_EXCEPTION");
    }

    this->IDsetInputXML = this->JNIEnvironment->GetStaticMethodID(this->javaClass, "setInputXML", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if (this->IDsetInputXML == NULL) 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("JAVA_INIT_METHOD_EXCEPTION");
    }

    this->IDgetInputXML = this->JNIEnvironment->GetStaticMethodID(this->javaClass, "getInputXML", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
//} <- This brace must be further down
    if (this->IDgetInputXML == NULL) 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("JAVA_INIT_METHOD_EXCEPTION");
    }
} // <- To here
```

I am sure it is just a typo, but if not, it may be the cause of the problems in your original example.

Comment: It works! You really saved my day! Thank you so much for taking the time to look into my code! Wow. Thank you sir!!

- Yes it was a typo mistake, I edited my question.

Comment: Moral: don't write JNI method signatures by hand. Use the output of `javap -s.` It is never wrong. And check the result of every JNI call, as I commented above.

Comment: See my comment on the question c.1 minute before this for how to check.